# How to force Save and restrict Open

Tags: html

In my html code, I have a link to a csv file. Ones a user click on it, the default program (MS Excel) starts and give two options : `Open` and `Save`

```
<a href="\\C:\xxx\test.csv">Download Data</a>
```

I need to restrict the `Open` option. I want the user to be able to do download it to his/her computer, but not open the version that is on my drive. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not stop the user from choosing the open option, but I think you are getting it wrong here - this only means his pc will download it and open it from his temp folder right away. He will not edit your version of that file.